# What is an easy way for disabling a file temporary?

Tags: web-development

Say I have a file called debug.php and I want to use it only when I am testing scripts.

- How can I disable the file securely?

I'm used to change it to a txt file. But I wonder what other users think is the best method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to a text file doesn't disable it. And if it is called from somewhere you'll get errors if you have `error_reporting` enabled. And it might be visible for clients of you change the extension, because a .txt file will not be parsed using PHP.

Since you want the file to only be used when in 'debug mode' I would simply either wrap it in a `if-statement` or if it is a function add a if-statement with a return void. And set a debug mode constant to be able to switch easily. E.g.

```
define('DEBUGMODE', true); // set this somewhere in your project as soon as possible
```

debug.php

```
<?php

if (DEBUGMODE === true) {
    // do the stuff
}
```

or

```
<?php

debugFunction() {
    if (DEBUGMODE === true) return;

    // do the stuff
}
```

Comment: +1 for still being visible: the server will almost certainly just push a .txt file source to the browser, which is arguably more dangerous than actually executing (depending on what the file does).

Comment: But I've got a file that I use as a test file. E.g. to manually make a pass hash. I want to use a 'change-file-name-solution'. What would you suggest?

Comment: I still don't see why you would change the name, but if you really want to go for the name change thing you can name it anything you want as long as the extension stays the same.